# Cant fix ValueError: Invalid parameter criterion for estimator for MultiOutputClassifier and GridSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to write a code for `MultiOutputClassifier` in Python using `scikit learn`. I have text values so I used `CountVectorizer()`, and I want to find the best parameters for my model so I used `GridSearchCV` and `model.best_params_`.
Best parameter for decision tree and for MultiOutputClassifier.

I get the error and I do not know how to fix it, I looked everywhere:

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter criterion for estimator MultiOutputClassifier(estimator=DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
            max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
            min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, presort=False, random_state=None,
            splitter='best'),
           n_jobs=None). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

How can I fix this error?
This is the full code:

```
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

df = pd.DataFrame({"first":["yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "no"],
                  "second":["yes", "no", "no", "yes", "yes"],
                  "third":["true","true", "false", "true", "false"]})

#print(df)

features = df.iloc[:,-1]
results = df.iloc[:,:-1]

cv = CountVectorizer()  
features = cv.fit_transform(features)

features_train, features_test, result_train, result_test = train_test_split(features, results, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 42)

tuned_tree = {'criterion':['entropy','gini'], 'random_state':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]}

cls = GridSearchCV(MultiOutputClassifier(tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()), tuned_tree)
model = cls.fit(features_train, result_train)

acc_prediction  = model.predict(features_test)
accuracy_test = accuracy_score(result_test, acc_prediction)

print(accuracy_test, model.best_params_)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the parameter of MultiOutputClassifier using `estimator__` prefix.

Try this

```
{'estimator__criterion':['entropy','gini']}
```

Note: You should not be tuning the random_state for any reason. Just you that for reproducibility.

You need to binarize the labels (target variable) for computing metrics in multi-label setting.

For multi-label format, stratified train- test splitting is not defined in sklearn. Hence, you have to do random splitting of train-test and then apply binarization.

In sklearn, lot of metrics available for multi-label task, check [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#multiclass-and-multilabel-classification).

```
import pandas as pd  

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, f1_score
from sklearn import preprocessing


df = pd.DataFrame({"first":["yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "no"],
                  "second":["yes", "no", "no", "yes", "yes"],
                  "third":["true","true", "false", "true", "false"]})

train, test = train_test_split(
    df, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 42)

# vectorization
cv = CountVectorizer()  
# always fit the vectorizer on the train data alone
# fitting on complete data leads to data leakage

features_train_vect = cv.fit_transform(train.iloc[:,-1])

# label binarization
mlb = preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer()
result_train = mlb.fit_transform(train.iloc[:,:-1].values) 

# applying the transform in test data
result_test = mlb.transform(test.iloc[:,:-1].values)
features_test_vect = cv.transform(test.iloc[:,-1])


params_range = {'estimator__criterion':['entropy','gini']}


cls = GridSearchCV(MultiOutputClassifier(tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=1),),
                   params_range, cv=3)
model = cls.fit(features_train_vect, result_train)

f1_score(cls.predict(features_test_vect), result_test, average='weighted')
# 0.6666666666666666
```

Comment: Ok, but do I need to do `preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer()`?
I just wanted to find the best parameters for my decision tree.

I have used `GridSearchCV(tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(), tuned_parameters)` when my code is without `MultiOutputClassifier`

Comment: `MultiLabelBinarizer` is required for when with multi-label problem. `GridSearchCV` can work without `MutliLabelBinarizer` for one target variable only.

Comment: @ai_learning ok but I want to get best parameters for my decision tree model and for my mulitioutput classifier, i want to use ` model.best_params_`, thats why I used `tuned_tree `, I see that you put parameters for decision tree by yourself

Comment: The code that I suggested tunes parameters of decision tree only. There is no parameter for multioutputclassifier, it's just a extension of estimate for multiple target vqriables.

Comment: I have just changed your varaible name from tuned_tree to params_range for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the `DecisionTreeClassifier()` *constructor function* to the `MultiOutputClassifier`. Try instantiating a decision tree *estimator object* and passing that to the function:

```
dtc = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
cls = GridSearchCV(MultiOutputClassifier(dtc), tuned_tree)
```

Comment: still the same error. 
Also, i do not think that this way will give me the parameters for decision tree

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary passed should be like

```
tuned_tree = {'estimator__criterion':['entropy','gini'], 'estimator__random_state':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]}
```

The `estimator__` prefix is required for all the parameters